Can I scale in the number theoretic transform? cNTT(p) = NTT(cp)?
The number theoretic transform is the analogous to FFT but discrete and on the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p$.
We can multiply polynomial modulo $xˆn + 1$ by doing:
$$p*q = INTT(NTT(p).NTT(q))$$
where $.$ means here the coefficient-wise product of the polynomials.
The question is: can I add and scale things in NTT form? That is: is it true that:
$$NTT(a) + NTT(b) = NTT(a+b)$$
and
$$cNTT(p) = NTT(c)$$
?
My guess is that if the first holds, then the second also does by induction. But how to prove the first?

DFT is matrix multiplication, i.e. a linear operation, so both formulae hold.
